# Please show me how to write a unique sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Below are the tables I need to pull data from - I only included columns to be used here in this example:

**Maintable**:

```
mainkey, account
-----------------
1, 100
2, 200
3, 300
```

**Childtable**:

```
linkedkeytomain, type, color
---------------------------
2, b, blue
2, y, yellow
2, r, red
2, g, green
2, w, white
```

My goal is to be able to write a select that will only show one line of data Where Type = 'b' and Type = 'w' and Type = 'r' only:

For instance,

```
Account, c1, c2, c3
---------------------
200, blue, white, red
```

Can someone please show me how to obtain this complex select. Many thanks in advance.

blumonde

Comment: Is each row in `Childtable` guaranteed to only have one color and 2 nulls? Are colors guaranteed to be mutually exclusive for `Childtable` items with the same foreign key? (ie would it be possible for 2 items to both have a c2). You're giving an example output without a description of the constraints.

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/  or use a pivot table (but that would be hard because your values aren't integers...)

Comment: Hi Dima, sorry, I corrected the example table. Please have a look again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to pivot the groups.  Here is a simple way:

```
select account,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as color1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then color end) as color2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then color end) as color3
from (select account, color,
             row_number() over (partition by account order by color) as seqnum
      from maintable mt join
           childtable ct
           on ct.linkedkeytomain = mt.mainkey
     ) t
group by account
```

Comment: assuming we know how many colors there are.... but yeah!  thanks for showing the whole code.  partitioning it was a good idea.

Comment: Also assuming SQL Server 2005+

Comment: It assumes that you know the max number of colors assigned to an account.  If you don't you need dynamic SQL to create the query, or to use a trick to concatenate the colors together in a group by.